# Atlassian Forge CLI "forge lint" "document must have at least 1 module error" what does the error mean

Tags: atlassian-forge

I created a simple Hello World Forge application using the Forge CLI by running `forge creae` and I chose the blank template which created an empty application with a `manifest.yml` and a `src/index.js` when I run `forge lint` or when I try to deploy with `forge deploy` (which also runs the linter before deploying) I get the lint error in the `manifest.yml` saying

```
error    document must have at least 1 module  valid-module-required
```

I am quite new to Forge and I don't understand what the error means or how to solve it, can someone explain and

By the way I tried look up for the module in the Forge manifest documentation but I don't seem to get something that explains whatt's happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forge uses [Modules](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/manifest-reference/modules/) to integrate your app with the product - creating a blank project won't add any modules automatically, so you'll need to choose one depending on how you want to integrate, and add it to the manifest.yml.

Another alternative (which will be easier if you're new to forge) would be to choose a template that is already using a module - so when you run Forge Create try selecting the UI type you want then the product you want to integrate with, then choose the module you want to use.

If none of this is making sense to you, then maybe you'd like to start by following a tutorial? Forge Quest aims to help you learn about Atlassian products and build a simple forge app. https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/tool/forge-quest/#welcome-to-forge-quest

Hope this helps!